# I cannot execute my Python code on Geany

Tags: python, windows-8.1, execute, geany

I use Windows 8.1 and installed Geany 1.24 recently. It launches without a problem but i cannot execute the code, because it gives an error saving file. What can be the problem?

Comment: "the file on disk may now be truncated", this is the error type.

Answer (score 1):

Either your disk is full or there is some interrupt which can cause by other programs' execution or something else that violates program execution.

You can check out [wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving) page of Geany for getting more info.

> If anything goes wrong in writing (disk full, network interruption) the file is likely to be truncated. On some file systems it is truncated to zero length. Geany will give a warning of possible truncation.